# make css files content available for production with Vite

Tags: vite

I have an application which uses Vite. It uses React with Typescript for client side and it uses for server side Asp Net Core with Razor. There are various css files on server and client. I have problems with css files which are part of the client structure. Their content is used/accessible in debug mode but not when I publish. It seems to me that Vite does not put that information in wwwroot. The rest works fine except for "client" css. I know that Vite does a lot of optimizations and css might be handled differently in case of "build" compared to "dev". As an example in NavMenu.tsx file I have

```
import './NavMenu.css';
```

That line may be commented out in debug mode and everything still works fine. On the other hand, when I build for publishing, it does not help. The files tsx and css are in the same folder

```
ProgMain
    wwwroot
    Client
        public
            css
        scss
        src
          ...
            components
                NavMenu.tsx
                NavMenu.css
    ...
    tsconfig.json
    vite.config.ts
```

I use

```
npm run dev
npm run build
```

both from Client folder. I put here part of vite.config.ts

```
export default defineConfig(async () => {
...
const config: UserConfig = {
    clearScreen: true,
    appType: 'mpa',
    root: 'Client',
    publicDir: 'public',
    build: {
        minify: false,
        manifest: appsettings.Vite.Manifest,
        emptyOutDir: true,
        outDir: '../wwwroot',
        assetsDir: '',
        rollupOptions: {
            input: ['Client/clientMain.ts', "Client/scss/site.scss"],
            output: {
                entryFileNames: 'js/[name].js',
                chunkFileNames: 'js/[name]-chunk.js',
                assetFileNames: (info) => {
                    if (info.name) {
                        if (cssPattern.test(info.name)) {
                            return 'css/[name][extname]';
                        }
                        if (imagePattern.test(info.name)) {
                            return 'images/[name][extname]';
                        }
                        return 'assets/[name][extname]';
                    } else {
                        return '[name][extname]';
                    }
                    ...
```

I would like a solution which does not involve enumerating each and single css file in Vite config. I would also like, if possible, to be able to keep css files in various folders, next to their tsx counterpart files so I don't have to group them all in same one folder.

I also thought that maybe is something typescript configuration related by tsconfig.json is pretty simple, does not seem to have anything to do with the problem.